# Update activity data (Data from cumming form server) without refresh activity

Tags: android, real-time

I have a question please help me. I make an app in which on a activity i get data from server. I have an admin panel in which there is form, I fill form and save data in Database. My question is i want when i save or update any data in Database the app show the new data without refresh the activity like cricket score updates etc. Please give your suggestions.

Comment: Whats do you mean by refresh?

Comment: Like my app show 10 balls 50 runs, and user stay on that activity. Then admin update data in Database and now new data is 20 balls 100 runs. I want to instant update of data in activity of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using Room database.

Databse class may look like this:

```
open abstract class MDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun dataDAO(): DataDAO
```

}

The Dao interface may look like the below:

@Dao
interface DataDAO {

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun saveData(dataEntity: DataEntity)

@Query(SELECT_ALL_DATA)
fun observeDB(): LiveData<Array<DataEntity>>
```

}

In the activity:

```
database.dataDAO()
.observeDB()
.observe(this, Observer<Array<DataEntity>> {
   //Update UI
})
```